# Get if an ellipse svg has been moved inside a path

Tags: javascript, html, svg, drag-and-drop

I have this svg code:

```html
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   id="svg4140"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg"
   onload="makeDraggable(evt)">
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="fill:#447fae;fill-opacity:1"
       d="m 99.23243,101.2138 216.30121,152.95767 0,-152.95767 -216.30121,0 z"
       id="blueTriangle"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:#b3c600;fill-opacity:1"
       d="m 99.236545,407.12692 216.301205,-152.95766 0,152.95766 -216.301205,0 z"
       id="rect4780-2"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <ellipse
       style="fill:#7f8184;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
       id="path4877"
       cx="190.71228"
       cy="355.38422"
       rx="74"
       ry="70"
       transform="matrix(0.92266592,-0.38560031,0.38560031,0.92266592,0,0)" />
    <ellipse
      class="draggable"
      id="outterCircle"
      cx="340"
      cy="218.36221"
      rx="54"
      ry="51" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

The ellipse with `id` "outercircle" is draggable and can be dragged inside the path with the `id` "blueTriangle".

What I want is to be able to know their coordinates when the ellipse is inside the path.

How can I do this please ?

Comment: Your question contains a few terms that need further explanation. Which "coordinates" do you want to know? SVG defines a lot of different coordinate systems. Yours has a viewport cs defined by the `viewBox`, one for the grey ellipse and one for displaying it in real-world media (`width` and `height` are in milimeters). What is "inside"? The whole of the ellipse on top of the triangle with no part sticking out, partially overlapping, the center of the bounding box (the tightest rectangle enclosing the form) of one over the bounding box of the other? Be precise.

Comment: @ccprog the coordinates I want to know are those of the viewport. I can deal with those in a start. 
"Inside" mean the whole of the ellipse on top of the triangle with no part sticking out.

Comment: That is a complex order, as the public API for SVG does not contain the needed methods. You'll need to use a third-party library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-intersections that finds intersections from mathematical analysis of the grafical shapes.

Comment: I will have a look at it. I manage to do it when I have two simple square by just comparing the x and y coordinates of the ellipse and the square. But for that much triangles it's more complicated.